# I have some locked files on my desktop how do i remove them?

Tags: permissions

I recently used Testdisk to recover some deleted files from usb stick, now I have these locked files on my desktop and when I try to remove them I get message saying I'm not the owner of these files and i don't have permission to change the. How can I move these files?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ownership of most any file with the chown command.  Once you own it, you can edit or delete it.  Since you don't already own the file you'll need sudo privileges to run this command.

`cd` to the directory containing the file you want to delete

**Changing ownership for individual files**

```
sudo chown your_username name_of_file_you_want_to_own

rm unwanted_file_name
```

**Changing ownership of entire directory and files contained therein**

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /path/to/folder
rm -r /path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

These files are likely owned by root if you recovered them with `testdisk`. Try removing them from the command line with `sudo rm -r ~/Desktop/FOLDER-TO-REMOVE`.

If you want to make a copy of them somewhere else, you should be able to copy them before removing.